# Remove special characters java

Tags: java, android, api

Hi I'm trying to figure out a way to remove the tags from the results returned from the Google Feed API. Their result is

```
   Breaking \u003cb\u003eNews\u003c/b\u003e Updates
```

How can we remove these characters?
I'm not sure if RegEx would be better (or worse). Does anyone have an idea on how to remove these? Google does not supply an option to remove tags from the results in Java.

Comment: Can you post explicitly what tags you want to remove??

Comment: Do you want to replace these: -  `\u003c`, `\u003e`??

Comment: yes, exactly, how can we remove those characters?

Comment: Use JSON to parse Feed data read the Google Guide https://developers.google.com/feed/v1/jsondevguide

Comment: I do the parsing only like the developers guide, but still i got the same problem

Comment: make as jsonobject and got answer, AurA pls make seperate answer i ll give you tick mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can use the below regex..**

```
String str = "Breaking \u003cb\u003eNews\u003c/b\u003e Updates";
str = str.replaceAll("\\<(.*)?\\>(.*)\\</\\1\\>", "$2");
System.out.println(str);
```

**OUTPUT**: -

```
Breaking News Updates
```

- `\\<(.*)?\\>` matches the first opening tag - `<b>`
- `\\</\\1\\>` matches the corresponding closing tag - `</b>`
- `\\1` is used to backreference what was the tag, so that correct pair of tags are matched..

So, `<b>news <update></b>` -> In this case `<update>` will not be removed..

Answer (score 1):

I pull those routinely with

```
String.replaceAll("\\p{Cntrl}","")
```

Comment: I guess \u003cb is not Java it must be json so that was the best I could do

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to use JSON to convert the data.

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({a : '<put your string here>'}));
```

It will be proper as the data you will get from Google API will be in the form of JSON.

Answer (score 0):

This is HTML. `\u003cb\u003e` translates to `<b>`.

You'll want to use an HTML parser as HTML is not fully parse-able by a regular expression.

With a library like Jsoup you could do this as.

```
String data = Jsoup.parse(html).body().text();
```

This will get you `"Breaking News Updates"`.